# Como guardar estado Tcombobox en un formulario y al abrirlo otra vez que este el Tcombobox igual que antes?

Tags: delphi

Tengo un formulario con una serie de `TComboBox` y `TEdit`s. Me gustaría que al darle a aceptar guarde esos datos y al volver abrir ese formulario se abra de la misma manera que lo cerre: con todos los `TComboBox` seleccionados, etc...

Trabajo en Delphi con Embarcadero RAD Studio XE6.

Ya probe con `TFormPlacement` de las RX, pero o algo hago mal o no me funciona...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay varias formas y/o lugares para guardar ese tipo de datos:

- **Base de datos**: Para esto deberás usar componentes de acceso a Base de Datos.
- **Ficheros en disco (INI)**: Para esto Delphi posee clases para trabajar con ficheros INI (`TIniFile`).
- **Registro de Windows**: Para esto puedes usar la clase que viene también con Delphi (`TRegistry`).
- ...

Con los componentes que comentas de las **RxLib**, podrás hacerlo en el registro o en ficheros INI, ya que implementan ambas opciones.

Si quieres probar a hacerlo a mano, por ejemplo utilizando un fichero INI, puedes utilizar un par de procedimientos como estos.

En el uses de tu `unit` añade:

```
uses
  Inifiles;
```

En la parte publica de tu formulario añade 2 procedimientos:

```
  procedure GuardarEstado();
  procedure RecuperarEstado();
```

La implementación será algo similar a esto:

```
procedure Tfrm1.RecuperarEstado();
var
  iniF:TIniFile;
  fName:String;
begin
  // El fichero se llamará igual que la aplicación pero extensión INI
  fName := ChangeFileExt(Application.ExeName, '.INI');
  // Tenemos que comprobar si el fichero existe...
  if FileExists(FName) then begin
    // Crear el fichero
    iniF := TIniFile.Create(fName);
    // Proteccion para liberar
    try
      // Recuperar los valores....
      edtDescripcion.Text := iniF.ReadString('CONFIG', 'Nombre', '');
      edtCodigo.Text := iniF.ReadString('CONFIG', 'Codigo', '');

      ...     <= El resto de elementos a recuparar

    finally
      // Liberarlo
      FreeAndNil(iniF);
    end;
  end;

end;

procedure Tfrm1.GuardarEstado();
var
  iniF:TIniFile;
  fName:String;
begin
  // El fichero se llamará igual que la aplicación pero extensión INI
  fName := ChangeFileExt(Application.ExeName, '.INI');
  // Crear el fichero
  iniF := TIniFile.Create(fName);
  // Proteccion para liberar
  try
    // Guardar los valores...
    iniF.WriteString('CONFIG', 'Nombre', edtDescripcion.Text);
    iniF.WriteInteger('CONFIG', 'Codigo', StrToInt(edtCodigo.Text));

    ...     <= Los elementos que quieras guardar

  finally
    // Liberarlo
    FreeAndNil(iniF);
  end;
end;
```

Deberás ir añadiendo más componentes en cada procedimiento. Tantos como desees almacenar.

Finalmente, por ejemplo, en el `OnShow` de tu formulario, deberás llamar al procedimiento `RecuperarEstado`, y en el `OnClose` del formularios al `GuardarEstado`.

En mi caso, una vez guardado el estado, en el mismo lugar donde se genera el EXE aparece un fichero .INI con un contenido como este:

> [CONFIG]
>
> Codigo=1
>
> Nombre=SEUR

A medida que vayas añadiendo más componentes y propiedades irán almacenendose en este fichero.